# Creating a horizontal rule (HR) divider that contains text with Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to create a `<hr>` divider using Tailwind CSS, but instead of the horizontal rule spanning the entire width of the page unbroken, I want to add some text in the middle.

For example:

```
----------------------------------- Continue -----------------------------
```

[image]

I can't find anything like this in the documentation. How can I achieve this effect?

If necessary, I can change the HTML to something other than an `<hr>` element. That was just the only way I knew how to create a horizontal rule.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use this HTML syntax to create what you want :

```
<div class="relative flex py-5 items-center">
    <div class="flex-grow border-t border-gray-400"></div>
    <span class="flex-shrink mx-4 text-gray-400">Content</span>
    <div class="flex-grow border-t border-gray-400"></div>
</div>
```

See here the result: https://play.tailwindcss.com/65JULZ5XES

Comment: If doesn't work, just add w-full to the parent div! Works for me!

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this effect using Tailwind CSS by creating a flex container with three items: two dividers and a text element. You can use the border utility to create the horizontal lines and the flex utility to align the items.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center">
  <div class="flex-1 border-t-2 border-gray-200"></div>
  <span class="px-3 text-gray-500 bg-white">Continue</span>
  <div class="flex-1 border-t-2 border-gray-200"></div>
</div>
```

In this code:

- `flex` makes the container a flex container.
- `items-center` vertically aligns the items in the middle.
- `flex-1` makes the dividers take up the remaining space in the container.
- `border-t-2 border-gray-200` creates a 2-pixel-thick, gray horizontal line.
- `px-3` adds horizontal padding to the text.
- `text-gray-500` sets the text color.
- `bg-white` sets the background color of the text to white, which creates the effect of the text interrupting the line.

**Example**

https://play.tailwindcss.com/FsC5mfR729

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<h1 class="text-center overflow-hidden before:h-[1px] after:h-[1px] after:bg-black 
           after:inline-block after:relative after:align-middle after:w-1/4 
           before:bg-black before:inline-block before:relative before:align-middle 
           before:w-1/4 before:right-2 after:left-2 text-xl p-4">Heading
</h1>
```

Comment: Is it possible it be dashed line?

Comment: I tried but not sure how to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Need to adjust the height, margin, bg-color, etc. to fit your website.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/FzGZ1fMOEL

```html
<div class="h-5 border-b-4 border-black text-2xl text-center">
  <span class="bg-white px-5">your text</span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```